# Codeigniter Online Visitors I can see how?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to show online users in the admin panel of the website.Thank you to everyone who responded.

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how to ?

Comment: Google is your friend, buddy!

Comment: I wrote here because I couldn't find there dude

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Library:-Online-Users

Comment: @Md.KhairulHasan Thanx. Yeah I saw it, but how do I use it ?

Comment: Check This it may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578691/check-if-a-user-is-online-codeigniter-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the users table you could create a column called online

```
Name    Type     Length / Val
online  tinyint     1
```

> Then when the user logins in. Update that user **online** column to `1`

Then on the a model function

```
public function countOnline() {
   $this->db->where('online', '1');
   $query = $this->db->get('users');

   return $query->num_rows();
}
```

> When the user logs out. You need to set that user online column to `0`

Model

Filename: Users_model.php

```
<?php

class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function countOnline() {
        $this->db->where('online', '1');
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}
```

Controller

Filename: Dashboard.php

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('users_model');
}

public function index() {
    $data['online_users'] = $this->users_model->countOnline();

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

}
```

To see new users online total you have to reload the page each time you want to see new users online.

There are scripts out there that can reload specific div's every few min.

Hope this gives you a idea

Comment: Thank you for your answer.There is no other way I think =)

Comment: That is the only simply quick and easy way I can think.

Comment: Well.I'll try it. Dude

Comment: You will have to refresh page though to see any new users online unless you have a script that can just refresh a certain div.

Answer (score 0):

First this is controller , so put here this code in your controller function,
than model function code put in your model file.

```
<?php
//controller function 
function total_user()
{
    /*load your model*/

    $data=$this->model_name->total_users_number();

    echo $data;

}

//model function 
function total_users_number()
{
   /*query*/ 
     $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM `users` where user_status='online'  // here your table name             
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->num_rows();
}
?>
```

Comment: That does not tell how many are online that just shows total number of users. As he said he wants to be able to see how many users online.

Comment: Yes, good idea. But I want the user not to see the guests.